# EL wf:actionData('sqoop-node') is not working

Tags: hadoop, oozie

```
<decision name="makeDecision1">
<switch>
    <case to="test1">${wf:actionData('sqoop-node')['V_GTM_STATUS'] eq 1}     
    </case>
    <default to="success"/> 
</switch>
</decision>
```

in above code control is not passing to test1. I want to pass control to test1 and then success, but workflow is skipping to test1 and directly passing control to the success, i think code is correct.

Comment: wf:actionData('sqoop-node')['V_GTM_STATUS'] eq 1 in this sqoop nodes output will be checked with expression wheather that keys values is eq to 1 then go to test1, but it is not working like that, and no error. any other way?

Comment: <switch xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2">
  <case to="test1">false</case>
  <default to="success" />
</switch>
instead of false it should be true, this is checked in action configuration

Comment: It is possible that you show more about your workflow? for example the 'sqoop-node' action and the point where the 'makeDecision1' decision is called?

Comment: <workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="SampleTest-wf">

<start to="sqoop-node"/>

   <action name="sqoop-node">

        <java>

            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>

            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>



    <main-class>fullyclassname</main-class>



        <arg>${SampleDir}/SampleWorkflow/lib/input1</arg>

 <arg>${SampleDir}/SampleWorkflow/output</arg>

 <capture-output/>

        </java>

   <ok to="makeDecision1"/>

          <error to="fail"/>

   </action>
is it fine?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some syntax issue with your code
The flower braces positioning will change in the below code

```
<decision name="makeDecision1">
<switch>
    <case to="test1">${wf:actionData('sqoop-node')['V_GTM_STATUS']}eq 1     
    </case>
    <default to="success"/> 
</switch>
</decision>
```